# I can't play audio and video sometimes

Tags: arch-linux, audio, video

Sometimes I can't play audio and video on my computer, both local files and online videos are affected. I can still drag the timeline bar and the image of that frame will show, but I just can't play it. Reboot the machine can solve the problem, but I want to know what cause it.

This is my spec:
OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64
Kernel: 5.4.17-1-MANJARO
Uptime: 24 mins
Packages: 1277 (pacman)
Shell: fish 3.0.2
Resolution: 2560x1440
DE: Plasma
WM: KWin
Theme: Breath-Dark [GTK2/3]
Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3]
Terminal: yakuake
Terminal Font: Noto Mono 10
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 1600X (12) @ 3.600GHz
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB
Memory: 3190MiB / 16012MiB

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Are you playing the audio and/or video using ALSA directly or through PulseAudio?

Comment: @Emmanuel Rosa I think it's through PulseAudio.

Comment: The behavior you describe reads like a conflict between two applications trying to access the audio hardware. This can certainly happen with ALSA but not with PulseAudio. Have you looked at the application's settings to ensure it is in fact using PulseAudio?

Comment: @Emmanuel I was using Bluetooth, and the module name is pulseaudio-modules-bt, I just assume it's through PulseAudio. Can you tell me how to identify what I am using?

Comment: You are using Bluetooth for audio. A problem with BT (e.g. if BT module hangs) may suspend playback and display the symptoms you are observing. When this happens, are you still able to use BT for something else than audio (e.g. sending/receiving files)? If you wait long enough, does audio eventually disconnect from BT and switch to your local loudspeakers? DOes `modprobe -r your-bt-module && modprobe your-bt-module` fixes things?

Answer (score 0):

install `ffmpeg` and then try `ffplay` to play the video

```
~ $ sudo pacman -S ffmpeg
```

After installation run

```
~ $ ffplay "path/to/video/file.mp4"
```

you can also try with `mpv`